# Function activity time out don't works

Tags: javascript, timeout

This is my activity timeout function, but don't works. I need help to know why, thanks!

First the function asks to user if he/she is here:

```
function activityTimeout(){
        //$("#jquery_jplayer").jPlayer("pause");

        clearTimeout(activityTO);

        blockInfoMsg('Are you here?.<br>(Automatic quit in <span id="spanActTO">60</span>seconds)<br><br><input type="button" value="Im here!" onclick="javascript:renewActivityTimeoutUnblock()" class="inputButton">&nbsp;or&nbsp;<input type="button" value="Quit Now!" onclick="javascript:abandonCorrection()" class="inputButton">', 0);

        popupTO = setTimeout(abandonCorrection, 60000);
    }
```

If the user is here then he/she is back to work and the function reset the timeout countdown:

```
function renewActivityTimeoutUnblock(){
        $.unblockUI();

        renewActivityTimeout();
    }

    function renewActivityTimeout(){
        clearTimeout(activityTO);
        clearTimeout(popupTO);

        activityTO = setTimeout(activityTimeout, 1800000);
    }
```

Comment: is `abandonCorrection` and `blockInfoMsg` an existing function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not `clearTimeout` and `setTimeout` in the same function (for the same timeout) because the function executed once, when the function is called.

```
function renewActivityTimeoutUnblock(){
    $.unblockUI();

    renewActivityTimeout();
}

function stopTimeout(){
    clearTimeout(activityTO);
}

function renewActivityTimeout(){
    clearTimeout(popupTO);

    activityTO = setTimeout(activityTimeout, 1800000);
}
```

Comment: Try with simple functions e.g alert() to check whether your function works or not.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you it's didn't work because you might be having this error `Uncaught ReferenceError: popupTO is not defined` in your javascript console.

Make sure those variables that you store the timeouts are declared.

```
function activityTimeout(){
    window.clearTimeout(activityTO);

    // make sure that this is an existing function in you js code
    blockInfoMsg('Are you here?.<br>(Automatic quit in <span id="spanActTO">60</span>seconds)<br><br><input type="button" value="Im here!" onclick="javascript:renewActivityTimeoutUnblock()" class="inputButton">&nbsp;or&nbsp;<input type="button" value="Quit Now!" onclick="javascript:abandonCorrection()" class="inputButton">', 0);

    // make sure abandonCorrection is an existing function, and this will timeout for 1 minute
    popupTO = window.setTimeout(abandonCorrection, 60000);
}

function renewActivityTimeoutUnblock(){
    $.unblockUI();
    renewActivityTimeout();
}
var activityTo;  // declare this variable like this
var popupTo;   // declare this variable like this

function renewActivityTimeout(){
    window.clearTimeout(activityTO);
    window.clearTimeout(popupTO);

    // take note of your time here it's 1,800,000 ms that's about 30 minutes
    activityTO = window.setTimeout(activityTimeout, 1800000);
}
```

Take note of your time, the activityTimeout will kick in after 30 minutes.  Try to lower it so that you can see.  Then use alerts or console log for your own debugging.

Here is a short demo of the **[timeout working](http://jsfiddle.net/fktfrngc/)**, it's delayed for 3 seconds before a console.log and alert pops up.   Hope this helps you.

**NOTE:**
Don't confuse setTimeout with setInterval.

**setTimeout** is just a delay, and executes only once. **[Read more about it here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout)**

setInterval on the other hand is like a loop, that will keep on calling the function during every time interval you set **[Read more about it here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval)**

To learn more about window timers **[just go here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Timers)**

Comment: Thanks! But it still don't works! Indeed in your demo the renew function don't works!

This is the abandonCorrection function:

    function abandonCorrection(){
   window.onbeforeunload = null;
   
   window.location.reload();
  }

Comment: @QUIEROHACERLO ehhh? In the demo you didn't see the alert popup?  It shows after 3 seconds.  In the jsfiddle demo it's just a short version of your code just to show you how how setTimeoutWorks

Comment: I only see it one time! 3 seconds after I accepted the alert, nothing happens!

Comment: @QUIEROHACERLO I think you are confusing setTimeout with setInterval read my updated answer about it.

Comment: thanks! Yes, I'm confused. I want to execute the function when the user don't make nothing, not autmatically each 3 seconds or once. Thanks again!

Comment: @QUIEROHACERLO Your welcome. If this helps you can mark the answer, it might be helpful to other to see which answers works or helps you.

Comment: If it doesn't work then it's not in the timeout or interval. You might be having a javascript error in your overall code.  Also do take note you time set on the timeout is **1800000 which is 1,800,000 ms = 30 minuites**  So you need to wait 30 minutes before you can see this works. Unless to change the time to a much lower value.  You also need to check for javasript errors in your console, cause If there is an error it will break the function executions.  There is nothing wrong with the way you are currenly using the timeouts so just check for errors or check you code maybe if has flaws.

Comment: Thanks, yes I changed to a lower value... And I declared ActivityTo and PopupTO variables at the beginning of the file

Comment: I checked for javascript errors in the console, and is not there the problem